# Jump to PDF from chapter source file

Tags: errors

I have one file named `test.tex` having the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
hello
\include{chapter1}
\end{document}
```

and another file named `chapter1.tex` in the same folder:

```
\section{Introduction} \label{ch:introduction}
This is introduction.
```

I can jump from the PDF to the location of the source code, but I cannot jump from the `chapter1.tex` file to the PDF. When I right click 'This is introduction', then 'Jump to pdf'. It gives an error 'File not found'. How do I solve this issue? I am using Texmaker.

I have searched the Internet, and did not find the same problem. I think the error message is because it was looking for the file `chapter1.pdf`. But there is only the file `test.pdf`. This problem happens when I have multiple `.tex` files. When there is only one `.tex` file, I can jump both ways.

Comment: If you have both files open, while test.tex is visible, you should be able to go into "Options> Define Current Document As Master Document". If you switch back to chapter1.tex, you should be able to compile test.tex and jump to test.pdf while editing chapter1.tex, I think. (I don't actually use texmaker, but I think that's how it works.)

Comment: @frabjous Thank you! That works!